# Android Material Design Activity Exit Animation Shows White Screen

Tags: android, material-design, activity-transition

I am trying to implement a simple activity transition effect in my android application, but whenever I back press on my SecondActivity my device shows white screen, i.e my FirstActivity becomes invisible.

My code is as follows:-

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/slide_to_bottom</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/slide_to_bottom</item>
</style>
```

slide_to_bottom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:duration="3000">

  <slide
     android:slideEdge="bottom">
  </slide>

</transitionSet>
```

I am starting my SecondActivity using this code

```
startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
                            FirstActivity.this).toBundle());
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding two more lines to styles.xml my animations are working properly.

```
<item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">false</item>
<item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">false</item>
```

because this property is true by default.